# Django Rest Framework combine multiple querysets in one api endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I connect the output of lists of a particular model, whose instances are filtered by different fields? For example, I have an Places model and two different url. In one, the entire list is displayed, and in the other only the instances with new_place = True.
Do an API using django-filter.

**models.py**

```
class Places(models.Model):
    main_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'album/')
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    new_place = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    editor_choice = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name = "Editors choice")
    most_popular = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name = "Most popular")
```

**serializer.py**

```
class PlaceSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
    view_name='places_api:detail',
    lookup_field='pk'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Places
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'main_photo',
            'name',
            'new_place',
            'most_popular', 
            'editor_choice',                        
        )
```

**full_list_views.py**

```
class PlacesListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Places.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlaceSerializer
```

**new_places_views.py**

```
class PlacesNewListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Places.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlaceSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('new_place',)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^new/$', views.PlacesNewListAPIView.as_view(), name = 'list_new'),
url(r'^$', views.PlacesListAPIView.as_view(), name = 'place_list'),
```

This all works well on different urls. But what should I do to get both lists on one page. List of NEW at the top and full list at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what output you want? Would it be ok to just use  `Places.objects.order_by('-new_place')` ?

Comment: I updated my  question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this. Using [`QuerySet.union()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union) to merge several querysets.

This example does not support pagination. I suspect that you would have to write a custom pagination class if you need pagination.

```
class MultiFilterPlacesListView(ListAPIView):
     """Custom queryset api view. Does not implement pagination"""

     pagination_class = None
     queryset = Places.objects.all()
     slice_size = 10  # count limit for each of the source queries

     def get_queryset(self):
         """Combine queries from new, editor choice and popular"""
         new_qs = self.queryset.filter(new_place=True)[:self.slice_size]
         editor_qs = self.queryset.filter(editor_choice=True)[:self.slice_size]
         popular_qs = self.queryset.filter(popular=True)[:self.slice_size]

         return new_qs.union(editor_qs, popular_qs, all=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update query in PlacesListAPIView with Places.objects.order_by('-new_place'). It will place new places at the top and others are on the bottom

```
class PlacesListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Places.objects.order_by('-new_place')
    serializer_class = PlaceSerializer
```

There is no need of separate URL for list of new places.

Comment: Well, what if I need to display on one page not only new places but also places filtered by fields : editor_choice and most_popular?

Comment: Not understand the point., For filtering on multiple fields you should use Djangofilter backend and pass filter params as query params